# Trying to use exec executable in ant to run R

Tags: java, r, ant

I am using the following open source version of image J in an experiment:

https://github.com/pcj/arterioj

it uses ANT.

Of of the ant targets is:
stats

```
 <!-- ================================================================ -->     
 <!-- Stats and plot generation tasks -->
<!-- ================================================================ -->

 <target name="stats">
<exec executable="R">
  <arg line="--vanilla --no-readline --quiet --slave --file=${basedir}/ldip-data.R --args"/>
</exec>
</target>
```

when I try to use this target I get the following build error message:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/James/ArterioJ/build.xml:179: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "R" (in directory "/Users/James/ArterioJ"): error=2, No such file or directory

I am unsure how to fix this. I have tried to copy the R package into the /users/James/ArterioJ directory to see if that would help but to no effect.

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually install R or just download the package? `sudo apt install r-base-core`

Comment: Yep sure did, use R for other things and it works well (doing all of this on a mac if that changes things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to specify the full path of the R executable, for instance:

```
<property name="r.home" value="/home/me/R_INSTALL"/>

<target name="stats">
  <exec executable="${r.home}/R">
    <arg line="--vanilla --no-readline --quiet --slave --file=${basedir}/ldip-data.R --args"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Alternatively, if the path to the executable is part of the `PATH` environment variable, you could just add the `searchpath="true"` attribute to the `exec` task:

```
  <exec executable="R" searchpath="true">
    <arg line="--vanilla --no-readline --quiet --slave --file=${basedir}/ldip-data.R --args"/>
  </exec>
```

Here is an extract from the Ant [documentation about searchpath](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html):

> When this attribute is true, then system path environment variables
>   will be searched when resolving the location of the executable